# Why does GLOB sort even if i use GLOB_NOSORT

Tags: php

I have this here

```
$smarty_versions = glob("php/Smarty-3.1.*", GLOB_NOSORT);
```

this outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => php/Smarty-3.1.13
    [1] => php/Smarty-3.1.19
    [2] => php/Smarty-3.1.2
)
```

the folder php folder looks like

```
php/Smarty-3.1.2
php/Smarty-3.1.13
php/Smarty-3.1.19
```

why does glob still sort even if i use GLOB_NOSORT ?

Comment: Interesting question, but I would interpret this flag as "Dear glob, I don't need sorting, so do as you see best". Maybe glob returns files in a different (accidentally sorted) order because it uses a different API than the one generating the directory listing.

Comment: actually it says: `GLOB_NOSORT - Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting)` and the result isn't like described

Comment: I mean to say: the directory listing is also just a listing, which may for whatever reason have a specific sort order as well. I think the wording in the PHP documentation is a bit unclear. It should say: "Return them as-is, as returned by the API". That is not necessarily the same order as the listing. I'm not saying that is the case. Maybe there *is* a bug in this flag, I don't know, but I wouldn't trust the directory listing per se. How did you get the listing, by the way?

Comment: @GolezTrol you mean the second part of my post ? its the regulare windows listening. im tesing my script on localhost (xampp-apache).

Comment: But Windows Explorer also sorts the files. It is even 'smart' so it doesn't do alphabetical sorting, but actually inspects the numbers in the file names and sorts by them as well, which is why 2 can be before 13. Can you open a command prompt, navigate to the right directory and use the `dir` command?

Comment: @GolezTrol you are right. cmd list dir with .13,.19,.2

Comment: So fortunately, it works. :) You might want to consider deleting this question. After all, there wasn't really a problem, so it's unlikely to get it answered anyway. ;)